# div getting hidden only in IE 10 / 11

Tags: html, css, knockout.js, internet-explorer-10

I have a simple HTML structure, which works fine in most browsers, but in IE 10 / 11 the top div is not shown.
As can be seen from the code segment below, I use knockout to control the visibility of the div that contains the problematic div (ClassA) by adding a class to make it visible and add animation. Except for the first div, everything else contained in the parent (ClassA) works fine.

```
    <div class='ClassA' data-bind="css: { 'classB': isVisible } ">
        <div class='selectionHeader'>
            <h2 class='selectionTitle'>Select Data</h2>
        </div>
        <div class='selectionContent'>
         ...
```

The div is there in the DOM in IE, but is not taking up space and when you hover over it, it shows above the div that contains it, instead of being inside it.
I found that if I play with the div's display status in IE's developer tools, going to display:none and then back, the div suddenly shows, but this does not persist and if I reload the page, it's hidden again.

I tried clearing the cache but that did not help.

Anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check your HTML structure, chances are you have an unclosed div somewhere.

Comment: I checked. All tags are closed. Also, wouldn't that also affect the rest of the HTML? Everything works fine except for that first DIV...

Comment: It usually affects the content after but sometimes it's only part of it that is affected. Can you add the rest of your code in a fiddle.

Comment: It's complex code that mixes knockout and LESS code. When I tried to simulate it  in a jsfiddle, it works fine. I'm not sure if it's the fact that it's inside the fiddle or the way I made it, but I can't seem to reproduce it on its own.

Comment: Does the broken HTML solution explain the behavior when I set it in the dev tools to display:none and back?

Comment: I don't know which dev tools you are talking about, but you can see if you html is valid by using this website http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Well, I solved it by adding display none in JS, and then removing it after a second. I found that any less that 700ms and the div comes back, but its height is wrong.

Comment: @llank just FYI Knockout has a `visible:` binding for simple (transitionless) hide/display

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of that. We used a different method to implement animation. I tried to use the visible binding on the problematic div, but that did not solve the problem.